# String converted To Dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a String format of JSON

```
 {
    abstract = "Today P.M of India Mr. Narender Modi visited for the eve of Agarasen \njayanti
\n";
    created = 1444733102;
    imgUrl = "";
    nid = 12;
    title = "Latest news";
}
```

I want to converted To NSDictionary

```
NSError *jsonError;
NSData *objectData = [[[tableDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"NewsValue"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&jsonError];
NSLog(@"%@",json);
```

They Give response is Null Please Help.

Comment: where it from? web service

Comment: If I copy/paste your "String" into a JSON Validator, it's not proper. From where do you get it? It seems to be already in a NSDictionary format.

Comment: check what jsonError giving and also check objectData is not null

Answer (score 0):

This is already in Json data of dictionary formate.

so you need not convert. Just retrieve data.

```
NSString * abstract = [Dic valueForKey:@"abstract"];
```

Answer (score -1):

Please used below code

NSData *objectData = [[[tableDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"NewsValue"] 
    NSString *strResponce = [[NSString alloc] objectData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[strResponce dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];
```

if([dictResponse isKindOfClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]]) {

NSString * abstractStr = [dictResponse valueForKey:@"abstract"];

}